# How can i use pseudo element ::before, ::after in material-ui

Tags: css, material-ui, pseudo-element

In mui, use the pseudo-element to write the method. I do not know how to use docs, so I post a question.

The pseudo elements mentioned in the docs are:

> box-sizing is set globally on the  element to border-box. Every element—including *::before and *::after are declared to inherit this property, which ensures that the declared width of the element is never exceeded due to padding or border.

That's all I do not understand.

I need help. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we define a width of a div, it can either include border width or not in total width.

suppose if we say -

> div { width: 10px; border: 10px solid grey; box-sizing: content-box}

```
in content-box as box-sizing, total width of div becomes 100 + 10 + 10.
```

> div { width: 10px; border: 10px solid grey; box-sizing: border-box}

```
in border-box as box-sizing, total width remains 100px;
```

Every element either its children or pseudo elements like ::before, ::after, all inherit same box-sizing value, what is defined in parent.